# How to keep a program always running in Windows?

Tags: windows, atom-editor

I'm using the Atom text editor, but it takes 1-2 seconds to start. That doesn't seem like long, but it's annoying because I open it probably 100 times a day. Is there a way to make it not actually close when I click "x"? E.g. either make it impossible to close or let it minimize to the notification area when I close it.

Comment: **If** the software doesn't have such an option then I know of a way to make it start back up if it's not found to be running in memory. You'd have to schedule another process to check for this though.

Answer (score 0):

Like what Leo said, you cant make it do what you mentioned. Simply refrain from closing it, and rather minimise it. You may be able to fibd sonething that puts it in the system tray rather than the taskbar when you minimise it. You could try a program called Windows Hider.